# Mysql : how i can get 3 columns from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

Forums:

```
+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+
| forum_id  |user_profile_id |profile_forum_id |profile_role |profile_status |
+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+
|         9 |              7 |               2 | moderator   | active        |
|        10 |              1 |               2 | admin       | active        |
|        40 |              1 |               1 | admin       | active        |
+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+
```

DDX:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| id |profile_id |profile_name | DDX_content   |profile_forum_id |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
|  2 |         1 | user1       | 874420        |               1 |
|  3 |         1 | user2       | 124500        |               2 |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Now i want to get list of all users(with 3 columns: profile_name, DDX_content, profile_role)  that have 'admin' or 'moderator' role for specific forum id. How i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this request :

```
SELECT
    d.profile_name,
    d.DDD_content,
    f.profile_role
FROM
    DDX AS d
    INNER JOIN
        Forums AS f
        ON f.profile_forum_id = d.profile_forum_id
WHERE
    (profile_role = 'admin' OR profile_role = 'moderator')
    AND forum_id = 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ddx.profile_name, ddx.DDX_content, f.profile_role
from ddx
join forums f on f.user_profile_id = ddx.profile_id
where profile_role in ('admin','moderator')
and forum_id = 123
```